# Integrate vasturiano / `sunbrust-chart` with Angular 2-9

Tags: angular, typescript, sunburst-diagram, angular9

It is there a way to integrate vasturiano/sunburst-chart with Angular 2 - 9? I am trying this, but is not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Sunburst from 'sunburst-chart';
import { sbdata } from '../chart-options/sunburst-mockdata';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sunburst',
  templateUrl: './sunburst.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sunburst.component.scss']
})
export class SunburstComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const myChart: Sunburst = Sunburst();
    myChart.data(sbdata)('sbChart');
  }
}
```

And the `sunburst.component.html`:

```
<div class="card" id="sbChart"></div>
```

Here are the sources of the `sunburst-chart`: https://github.com/vasturiano/sunburst-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have a working solution with Angular 9 style.

Install: `"sunburst-chart": "^1.8.0"` and if you want also `"d3": "^5.15.0"`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Sunburst from 'sunburst-chart';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sunburst',
  templateUrl: './sunburst.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sunburst.component.scss']
})
export class SunburstComponent implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean;

  @ViewChild('sbChart', { static: true }) sbChartEl: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired);
    const sbdata = {
      name: 'main',
      color: 'magenta',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'a',
          size: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'b',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'ba',
              size: 1
            },
            {
              name: 'bb',
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'bba',
                  size: 1
                },
                {
                  name: 'bbb',
                  size: 1
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    Sunburst()
      .data(sbdata)
      .size('size')
      .height(500)
      .showLabels(false)
      .tooltipContent((d, node) => `Size: <i>${node.value}</i>`)
      //.color(d => color(d.name))(document.getElementById('sbChart'));
      .color(d => color(d.name))(this.sbChartEl.nativeElement);

    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```

The `sunburst.component.html` file:

```
<div [hidden]="loading">
  <div id="sbChart" #sbChart></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will this create hierarchal data like 3 layered data right

Comment: How can we rotate text to centre like this example 
https://observablehq.com/@d3/sunburst

Comment: @ammadkhan Yes, will be with 3 layers.

Comment: @ammadkhan There is `labelOrientation([angular, radial or auto])`. Please check the documentation: https://github.com/vasturiano/sunburst-chart. If this does not help, you can manipulate manually the CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much i look into it

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

index.html:

```
...

  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sunburst-chart@1.8.0/dist/sunburst-chart.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Open your app.component.ts and add the following code:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
declare var Sunburst: any;
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "my-app";
  data: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = {
      name: "main",
      color: "magenta",
      children: [
        {
          name: "a",
          color: "yellow",
          size: 1
        },
        {
          name: "b",
          color: "red",
          children: [
            {
              name: "ba",
              color: "orange",
              size: 1
            },
            {
              name: "bb",
              color: "blue",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "bba",
                  color: "green",
                  size: 1
                },
                {
                  name: "bbb",
                  color: "pink",
                  size: 1
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    Sunburst()
      .data(this.data)
      .size("size")
      .color("color")(document.getElementById("chart"));
  }
}
```

Next in your app.component.html:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

it should work properly!

Comment: Thanks, this solution is showing the sunburst-chart!